# HTML input - getting the value via innerHTML or XMLSerializer

Tags: javascript, html, serialization

I have an input box on a html page.  I know I can get just the value, but I want the entire input string, i.e. , but with the value present:

```
<input id="myInput" value="my entry that I just typed in"/>
```

I have tried innerHTML, I have tried XMLSerializer, etc.

```
var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('myInput');
var str = s.serializeToString(htmlDiv);
```

The value is always empty.

If you are wondering why I want to do this - it is because this is my simple example of what in reality is about 60 inputs, all part of an HTML string that I want to send to XSLT translation.  That part works like gangbusters, I just have to get it HTML with values intact.

Another related problem is that innerHTML has a nasty habit of getting rid of the / at the end of the input box, which throws off the XSLT translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("myInput").outerHTML);
```

```html
<input id="myInput" value="my entry that I just typed in"/>
```

And if you want to add / at the end:

```js
myVar = document.getElementById("myInput").outerHTML;
if(myVar.charAt(myVar.length - 1) !== "/"){
console.log(myVar.slice(0, myVar.length-1) + "/>");
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" value="my entry that I just typed in"/>
```

Comment: The first tip did not work, the second tip did.
What doesn't make it to the outerHTML (or inner) is the user's change to the input.  I think it is only in the DOM.  This is the code:

    <div>
    <input id="myInput" />
    <button type="button" onclick="run()">RUN</button>
</div>
<script>
    function run() {
        console.log(document.getElementById("myInput").outerHTML);
    }
</script>

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following:  Serializing with XMLSerializer, which solved the / problem.  And I just got the values from the DOM and inserted them myself.

```
function htmlCleanup(htmlDiv) {

    //serialize the html.  It will lack the latest user changes in the inputs.
    var s = new XMLSerializer();
    var str = s.serializeToString(htmlDiv);
    var lines = str.split("\n");
    //get all of the inputs in the div
    var inputs = htmlDiv.getElementsByTagName('input');

    //Here we put in the latest values
    var inputIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var line = lines[i].trim();
        if (line.indexOf('<input') >= 0) {
            var value = inputs[inputIndex].value;
            lines[i] = fixInputValue(line, value);
            inputIndex++;
        }
    }

    str = lines.join('\n');
    //Some other weird aftertaste stuff that needs fixing. <tbody> is added to tables - wrongly.
    //the div at the top is also a problem.
    //Then we turn it all into proper xhtml for the trip back to the server.
    var contents = str.replace('<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="documentEditBody">', '');
    contents = contents.replace(/<tbody>/g, '');
    contents = contents.replace(/<\/tbody>/g, '');
    contents = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html><head></head><body><div>' + contents + '</body></html>';

    return contents;
}

function fixInputValue(input, value) {
    var valuePos = input.indexOf('value');
    var result = "";
    if (valuePos > -1) {
        for (var i = valuePos + 7; i < input.length; i++) {
            var chr = input[i];
            if (chr === '"') {
                var last = input.substring(i + 1, input.length)
                result = input.substring(0, valuePos - 1) + ' value="' + value + '" ' + last;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```